# Creating a supertype in MariaDB | syntax error

Tags: sql, syntax, mariadb

I tried to run this example query from https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/udt-example/ :

`CREATE TYPE book_udt AS                -- the UDT name will be book_udt
title CHAR(40),                        -- title is the first attribute
buying_price DECIMAL(9,2),             -- buying_price is the second attribute
selling_price DECIMAL(9,2)             -- selling_price is the third attribute
NOT FINAL                              -- this is a mandatory Finality Clause
METHOD profit( ) RETURNS DECIMAL(9,2); -- profit is a method, defined later`

but I get a syntax error. Does MariaDB do not support supertypes like MySQL doesn't? According to docs it does ... Does someone have experience with supertypes and knows what's wrong here?

Comment: Did you read the big disclaimer at the top? "Because the book is about the SQL-99 standard, the contents of this and other pages in the book may not directly apply to MariaDB."

Comment: Oh this explains a lot lol. Maybe this is why I had small issues with other stuff too but I was able to fix them. Still - maybe MariaDB does support this and someone knows how to do it?

Comment: Is there reason for focusing on SQL-99, not MariaDB/MySQL ?

Comment: @RickJames so far anything I've took from MariaDB wiki with SQL-99 examples worked most time without any struggles. What do you suggest Rick? Are there better/specific to MariaDB docs?

Comment: Suggest writing a bug with mariadb.com